# TypeError: sort() takes no positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to change a Python2 code into a Python3 code. There is a similar code to this?

```
indice.sort(lambda x,y: -cmp(topic[x], topic[y]))
```

`topic` is a float list.
`indice` is the `topic`'s index list. Like: `indice = list(range(len(topic))).`

Comment: Please read the basic documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the link given by λuser in their comment, the standard way in Python 3 (>= 3.2) is to use `functools.cmp_to_key`:

```
import functools
...
keyfunc = functools.cmp_to_key(lambda x,y: -cmp(topic[x], topic[y]))
indice.sort(key=keyfunc)
```

Comment: `cmp_to_key` is the quick-fix, "I have a lot of code to convert and not much time to think about it" solution. It's usually possible to do something much better. In this case, since `topic` is a list of floats, `key=lambda x: -topic[x]` would be shorter and more efficient.

Comment: Also, `cmp` was removed in Python 3.

Comment: But the code `cmp_to_key(lambda x,y: -cmp(topic[x], topic[y]))` is calling the `cmp` function again. i'm reading the basic documentation to try to understand what exactly this line do. And i'm little confused about why he uses 2 indexes, x and y, to compare and sort topic.

Answer (score -1):

Use `key = lambda ...`. The interpreter is saying that the sort method can't interpret your argument (the lambda expression) by its position, it needs the parameter name `key =`

Comment: But that function *isn't* a key function. It's a comparator. Catching this kind of situation is the primary reason why `key` is keyword-only - so comparators don't get silently interpreted as key functions.